# Best way to store player data like scores, rewards, login info, checkpoints etc for offline PC games?

Tags: unity, databases

I am creating a VR game in Unity, it will be an offline PC game. I want to store user login info, score, checkpoints, learning points, rewards etc in the database. I checked out firebase but it doesnt work for pc games apparently.
I only have Oculus Rift to test my game else I wouldve switched to android as which platform the end game is for doesn't really matter. What are some other good alternatives? What should I use for my pc game?

I will later use the score and rewards to create learning points which will then be processed in an ML model to perform categorization.

Moreover, it is possible that I integrate firebase with unity while keeping my game in Windows platform while I test it on Rift and in the end I build it for android so it works fine with firebase?

Comment: There is a lot of different things mixed up that don't really make sense together. Offline game and login info don't mix, where do you want to login when you don't go online? Firebase is a database, saying `doesnt work for pc games` means you implemented it not correctly. In case you want to fix that, make a question with your firebase implementation and the error you are getting. ML does not seem to have to do anything with the question, focus on one thing per question.

Comment: Firebase is an online database service from Google. Although it supports offline storage, this is supposed to be temporary until the user next goes online. It's not intended for a game that is always offline.

Comment: @Zibelas Firebase for Unity only officially supports iOS, Android, and the Unity Editor. The plugin currently is not intended for use with PC games.

Answer (score 1):

There's no single "best way" to store data. Which approach works best will depend on the complexity and volume of your data, and the way you interact with it.

With video game save data that just needs to be *loaded* rather than *queried*, a common solution is to serialize the data into a text (e.g. JSON) or binary format, and save that in one or more files.

If you're storing a very large amount of data, or data that's fairly complex or frequently queried, you can use a database. The easiest way to integrate a database is to find an existing C# library or Unity plugin for local database support; a common choice is SQLite, but you'll have to determine whether SQLite is appropriate for your use case.

If you determine that a database is the best solution for your needs, you should try to avoid anything that requires the player to install or run a database server.